# How to return when ref and ownership transfer both won't work

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

so, if I return this

```rust
self.string_ref.unwrap().as_ref()
```

compiler will say

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

if  I return this

```rust
*self.string_ref.unwrap().as_ref()
```

the compiler will say

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
```

this is just drove me crazy

here is the code: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9ca4251261a1311d8a37b79f83ee3d0))

```rust
use std::ptr::NonNull;

struct A {
    string_ref: Option<NonNull<String>>,
}

struct Number {
    num: i32
}

impl A {
    fn hello() {

    }

    fn give_me_string(&self) -> String {
        unsafe {
            *self.string_ref.unwrap().as_ref()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        string_ref: NonNull::new(&mut String::from("hello world") as *mut String)
    };
    let t = a.give_me_string();
    println!("{}", t)
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [ReprEx](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  (Hint: trying running it in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) may help)

Comment: @PeterVaro Changed

Comment: Side note, but: why do you need the `unsafe` here?

Comment: @Cerberus as_ref is an unsafe function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping your example to the bare minimum:

```rust
struct A {
    string_ref: Option<NonNull<String>>,
}
impl A {
    fn give_me_string(&self) -> String {
        unsafe {
            *self.string_ref.unwrap().as_ref()
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few errors here:

1. The most obvious one is that you're trying to take ownership of `self.string_ref`, even though you've only borrowed `self`.
   To solve this you'll want to use a `match` statement, which allows you to destructure `self.string_ref` and not consume it:

```rust
fn give_me_string(&self) -> String {
    unsafe {
        match self.string_ref {
            Some(x) => x.as_ref(),
            None => panic!("Had no `string_ref`!")
        }
    }
}
```

2. [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.as_ref) returns `&T`, so you can't return an owned string, instead you need to either clone it and *then* return an owned string, or take reference to it:

```rust
//Option one: Clone contents
match self.string_ref {
    Some(ref x) => x.as_ref().clone(),
    _ => //...
}
//Option two: Return reference. 
fn give_me_string(&self) -> &str {
    unsafe {
        match &self.string_ref {
            Some(x) => x.as_ref() as _,
            _ => //...
        }
    }
}
```

To address another problem mentioned in the comments, you have the following statement in your `main` function:

```
string_ref: NonNull::new(&mut String::from("hello world") as *mut String)
```

This will cause `UB` due to its nature. You are forming a `String` by using `String::from`, but are not storing its value anywhere and are instead immediately casting into a pointer. This will free the `String` at the end of the line, causing `UB`.

Comment: ```rust
fn give_me_string(&self) -> String {
    unsafe {
        match self.string_ref {
            Some(x) => x.as_ref(),
            None => panic!("Had no `string_ref`!")
        }
    }
}
```
x is owend by function give_me_string, returns a value referencing data owned by the current function won't work

Comment: if I cloned as your option one: ```rust Some(x) => x.as_ref().clone(),```, result will somehow ignore 8 chars from original string. e.g.  original: 12345678abc,  function return: "\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}abc" , so weird, seems been overided with zeros   [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55b79a5ae2e68a3c45f9a3ac8c4c81f5)

Comment: That's because you've got a read after free error, you call `String::from` and you end up dropping it after the line using it. Remember that `NonNull` is still a pointer type, and is not an owning type.

Comment: I've edited my cloning example to work better, it's now using a `ref` pattern.

Comment: add ref, same result  [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0ee0ef352e62e59f7682a3c6fe27b82)

Comment: will you please give me a working one playground link, so I can accept your answer, ref just won't work

Comment: Whoops, I got the wrong pattern  sorry for the mix-up! [Code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=42fc8f71bf229971a2bdf92996c144bd)

Answer (score 0):

So I basically figured out what's going on, thanks to  @Optimistic Peach

```rust
fn give_me_string(&self) -> &String {
        unsafe {
            match self.string_ref {
                Some(x) => &*(x.as_ptr() as *const _), //without ref
                Some(ref x) => x.as_ptr(), // with ref
                None => panic!("hello?")
        }
    }
}
```